# shift the elements of a vector by non-integer shift in matlab

Tags: matlab, fft, interpolation, shift

I want to shift a vector by non-integer shift, linear interpolation seems to be not very accurate so I'm trying to use *sinc* interpolation by the following code which uses Fourier transform.

```
function y = fshift(x,s)
% FSHIFT Fractional circular shift
%   Syntax:
%
%       >> y = fshift(x,s)
%
%   FSHIFT circularly shifts the elements of vector x by a (possibly
%   non-integer) number of elements s. FSHIFT works by applying a linear
%   phase in the spectrum domain and is equivalent to CIRCSHIFT for integer
%   values of argument s (to machine precision).


needtr = 0; if size(x,1) == 1; x = x(:); needtr = 1; end;
N = size(x,1); 
r = floor(N/2)+1; f = ((1:N)-r)/(N/2); 
p = exp(-j*s*pi*f)'; 
y = ifft(fft(x).*ifftshift(p)); if isreal(x); y = real(y); end;
if needtr; y = y.'; end;
```

there is no problem in the code when i shift a square wave by integer shift but when the shift is non-integer the output suffers from significant fluctuations
i.e.,

```
s=[zeros(1,20) ones(1,20) zeros(1,20)];
b=fshift(s,3.5);
stem(b)
```

How to overcome this problem and is there any other accurate method?

Comment: I am not really surprised actually. To me it looks like expected. I am not sure if there are a better way to do it so for that I cannot make a pronouncment about that. However, when you do an integer shift you will have frequency bins as a fraction of an integer, that is `f*s = -3:0.1:2.9` for `s=3`, Then you can be sure that each sample `x` (function x) really matches a bin. However, when `s` is a fraction (or a real number), the bins becomes non, fractional, which means that each value in `x` does not fit in a bin. This means that you will have leakage and this is what you see in the graph.

Comment: Fourier interpolation is often not the best choice. You have to deal with ringing and the  periodic boundary condition. Try cubic spline interpolation or Lanczos interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Let's say you are shifting by 3.5.  Figure out what the oversampling value is (i.e. what value will change the shift into an integer - in this case it is 2).

```
ov = 2;
a = 3.5*ov;
y = downsample(circshift(interp(s,2).', -a),ov);
```

This still has some ringing at the edges, but much less than your sinc approach.  I'm not sure if this is due to the gibbs phenomenon since you are essentially truncating or leakage, as mentioned in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the [fourier shift theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Shift_theorem) as you do, but with added filtering. I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45865328/apply-fourier-shift-theorem-to-complex-signal). The reason that the result looks 'wrong' is because your input vector is not continuous. The result you are getting really is 'correct' (or at least *true*).

The problem you are seeing is called [Gibbs Ringing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon#The_square_wave_example). You can make this less extreme by using a low pass filter ([this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringing_artifacts#Low-pass_filter) wikipedia link explains the solution pretty well) that has no ringing in its step response. Try your code with and without a [gaussian filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_filter). This artefact is often seen in MRI imaging (and many other signal processing situations) and is sometimes alleviated by filtering.

Answer (score 1):

Fourier shift theorem only works for integer values unless you are careful to make your frequency ramp continuous across DC. I've edited my answer below based on Cris Luengo's comment (thank you).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
 
def plotRealImag(x, y, xnew, ynew, title):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x, np.real(y), 'o-', x, np.imag(y), 'o-')
    plt.plot(xnew, np.real(ynew), '.-', xnew, np.imag(ynew), '.-')
    plt.legend(['y real', 'y imag', 'y new real', 'y new imag'], loc='best')
    plt.title(title)
     
def plotMagPhase(x, y, xnew, ynew, title):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x, np.abs(y), 'o-')
    plt.plot(xnew, np.abs(ynew), '.-')
    plt.legend(['y', 'y new'], loc='best')
    plt.title(title + " Magnitude")
     
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x, np.angle(y), 'o-')
    plt.plot(xnew, np.angle(ynew), '.-')
    plt.legend(['y', 'y new'], loc='best')
    plt.title(title + " Phase")
 
def sampleShift(y, shift):
    n = y.shape[0]
    Y = np.fft.fft(y)
    w = np.arange(n)/n
    w[-n//2:] -= 1 # Make phase ramp continuous across DC
    Ynew = np.exp(-2j*np.pi*w*shift)*Y
    ynew = np.fft.ifft(Ynew)
    return ynew
     
# Create data
n = 16
u = 10
x = np.linspace(0, 10, n, endpoint=False)
y = np.cos(-x**2/6.0) + 1j*np.sin(-x**2/6.0)
xnew = np.linspace(0, 10, u*n, endpoint=False)
 
# Shift data
shift = 0.3
ynew = sampleShift(y, shift)
delx = x[1]-x[0]
plotRealImag(x, y, x-shift*delx, ynew, "FFT Sample Shift")
plotMagPhase(x, y, x-shift*delx, ynew, "FFT Sample Shift")
 
plt.show()
```

Comment: You're right. My phase ramp was not continuous across DC, which was causing my incorrect result. It just happens to work out if you shift by an integer. I've corrected my example. Thanks!